# Change img src with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, src

Hey guys I need some help

Im trying to change the src of an image tag but when change it using my code it adds the word file to the start of my string.
The final result is `file:///C:/xampp/....`
instead of just  `C:/xampp/....`

Here is my code

```
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        alert(images[i].src);
        srcList.push(images[i].src);
        var index = srcList[i].search("JavaBridge");
        tempPath.push(srcList[i].slice(index-1, srcList[i].length));
        finalPath.push("C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps"+tempPath[i]);
        document.getElementById(images[i].id).src = " "+finalPath[i];
        alert(images[i].src);
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @CharlieFish I have some img tags in my HTML I want to change the src attribute of those img tags. In the 7th line of my code it gets the current src value and replaces it with the value of the array of finalPath. But when I try to alert he value to check it. Instead of just "C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps/..." it displays "file:///C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps/..."

Comment: Your question still makes no sense. What are you trying to do. What is the original state? How do you want to alter the original state?

Comment: It SHOULD display `file:///` in front of the files, that's the URI scheme for files accessed from the filesystem. Question is, are you doing this for testing or do you plan on using these files in this way in the final product? Because that wouldn't be a good idea

Comment: @CharlieFish The original img src is http://localhost:8080/Javabridge/sessionChartImage/1.jpg

Im trying to change it to
C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps/Javabridge/sessionChartImage/1.jpg

Comment: @JuanCarlosCabotaje Oh ok. Yeah as other people have said you need the file:/// part. Unless you setup a server on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

For file manager the physical path is `C:/xampp/....` but browser cannot use that directly. So, this is a default action and you cannot override it. Try to open a file with browser and see the url .. you will find `file:///` appended before the path.

When you change this path to url.. the `file:///` will not come.

One quick workaround is to use a server and load files using server.. You can easily setup server using apache (Xampp, Wamp) or Node (Gulp Task)

Comment: Ow okay. Thanks. 

I was only trying to change the src attribute because Im trying to send emails using my local. But when I check the email the images are broken.

So I thought I could alter the src attribute in order for it to display.

Comment: Off-course the images will be broken.. The code will work in your system only as `C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps` as this path is local to your system and images are present in your system only. 
while in receiver's pc .. the images are not there in `C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps` .. Host the images somewhere like imgur, tinypic and use that url in mail template.

Comment: I tried using PHPMailer function AddEmbeddedImage and sent a trial email to myself using `C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps` and it worked

Comment: yes because the you received the mail in your system only.. In other's system it will not work.. `C:/xampp/tomcat/webapps` this path has images only for your system.